# Windows Subsystem for Linux & SSH Port Forwarding

Tags: bash, ssh, port-forwarding, windows-10-v1607, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Is it possible to use SSH port forwarding in Windows Subsystem for Linux?

If I download the native OpenSSH package, I can forward ports:

```
> ssh -L 5432:localhost:5432 me@host
Welcome to Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.6.5-x86_64-linode71 x86_64)
etc
```

But if I try the same thing from within WSL bash:

```
$ ssh -L 5432:localhost:5432 me@host
bind: Address already in use
Welcome to Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.6.5-x86_64-linode71 x86_64)
etc
```

I am running bash as administrator (and have tried it not running as administrator as well).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Self answer:  See [this bug.](https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/674)  The following works:

```
ssh -L 127.0.0.1:5432:localhost:5432 me@host
```

The problem is that IPv6 doesn't work in WSL and the failure flows through to the IPv4 port forwarding.

Comment: Wish I had discovered this a few hours ago :)

Comment: In more detail: `ssh -L 5432:localhost:5432` implicitly means `ssh -L localhost:5432:localhost:5432`.  That first `localhost` gets looked up locally and Windows gives the IPv6 loopback address by default, so ssh tries to open a local IPv6 port 5432.  IPv6 doesn't work in WSL, so opening the port fails.  By explicitly giving `127.0.0.1` as the local address, you force ssh to use IPv4.

Comment: Would `ssh -4.... ` work to force IPv4?

Comment: @FelipeAlvarez - I don't know and I don't have one to hand to try it out, sorry.